# How do you reset your iCloud password if you don't know your password for iCloud

Tags: iphone

How do you reset your iCloud password if you don't know your password for iCloud

Answer (score 3):

Apple has [this handy tool](http://iforgot.apple.com) set up for exactly that purpose!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can reset your ID password using a recovery email or secret questions.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Be sure to add links and explain answers for people that ask vague questions. They often need the most help and/or hand holding.